# How to use authentication with negiotiation (e.g. Kerberos) to HTTP proxy?

Tags: proxy, http, squid, kerberos, http-proxy

Generally accepted is the use of `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to specify the use of a proxy server. Authentication can be included in this URL, e.g. `HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@myproxy.mydomain.tld:3128/`.

However, I am using Kerberos SSO to authenticate with the proxy. How do I configure that? So, suppose a Squid proxy server configuration as described here: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos. It describes how Windows clients can use proxy authentication with negotiation, but there's no information how I can configure Linux/Unix clients.

For cURL, the use of `--proxy-negotiate -u :` does the trick, e.g.:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.mydomain.tld:3128/ curl --proxy-negotiate -u : https://www.google.com
```

How do I tell non-cURL applications to use this mechanism? E.g. Debian/Ubuntu APT with `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://myproxy.mydomain.tld:3128/";`?

I found [cntlm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cntlm.1.html) which acts as another locally running proxy in the middle, facilitating unauthenticated connections from localhost. However, this only works with NTLM, where I need Kerberos. Would Squid be able to connect as a client using Kerberos perhaps? It seems notoriously hard to find authentication capabilities on the *outgoing* connection of proxy servers. All seem to focus on authentication features on the *listening socket* instead.

Comment: I use `cntlm` at work but not with `kerberos` so even I wouldn't be able to test it but a short googling led me to this: http://sourceforge.net/p/cntlm/feature-requests/_discuss/thread/4a3be422/22d0/attachment/201211-cntlm-kerberos-authentication.patch. Can you try it?

Comment: I applied this patch to `cntlm 0.92.3`, you can get the source code here http://drabczyk.org/cntlm-with-kerberos.tar.gz. You need to do `./configure  --enable-kerberos`.

Comment: Looking at the code you now need to pass `gss` to `-a`. Here on the bottom on the page https://github.com/metaphox/cntlm-gss some shows an example configuration.

Comment: The thing with kerberos authentication is that you need a _kerberos-aware_ version of each application you want to use through Kerberos. In addition to that, in case of http proxies you also need the http client to be capable of handshaking the kerberos authentication to the proxy-http server using the http Negotiate protocol. Something that curl knows how to do, but I’m afraid `apt` doesn’t. AFAIK, `apt` only supports either plaintext http-auth or socks5